# JAVA Sintaxis de un Arreglo

Tags: java, array, sintaxis

estoy intentando construir una matriz de objetos de la clase Pregunta.
Su metodo constructor es el siguiente:

```
    public Pregunta(String pregunta, String[] respuestas, int posicicionRespuesta) {
    this.pregunta = pregunta;
    this.respuestas = respuestas;
    this.posicion = posicicionRespuesta;
}
```

cuando la intento construir desde la clase Juego, y empiezo a escribir los parametros, aparece un error: **ilegal start of expression**

```
public class Juego {

Pregunta[][] clasePreguntas;
Categorias[] categoria;
Jugador[] jugadores;

public Juego() {
    clasePreguntas = new Pregunta[5][5];
    categoria = new Categorias[5];
    jugadores = new Jugador[10];
}
public void llenarMatrizPreguntas() {
    clasePreguntas[0][0] = new Pregunta("¿Cual es el apellido de Rodolfo?",{"Rodriguez","Maduro","Ordonez"}, 5);
}
```

Entonces ¿como puedo hacer que me reconozca el arreglo recibido como un parametro?

Comment: Prueba con esto en el segundo parámetro de **Pregunta** `new String[]{"Rodriguez","Maduro","Ordonez"}`

Comment: Eso es lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias companero.